# Unable to update an existing schema extension

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to add a few properties to an schema Extension with the Microsoft Graph API. Our extension is in development state and I'm obtaining an accesstoken with the same app Id which is owner of the extension.

The problem is that I always get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Cannot delete an existing property.",
"innerError": {
  "date": "2020-08-10T15:15:15",
  "request-id": "9344dbe9-084d-4bd9-a690-75fcd32db6bc"
}
}
}
```

The Following request is used:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions/<OurId>

{
"properties": [
{
  "name":"<name of first property>",
  "type":"String"
},
{
  "name":"<name of second property>",
  "type":"DateTime"
}
]
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention all properties - existing and new. If "properties" section contains only new properties you will get this error.